# An error "Null pointer Exception" is shown when executing feature file

Tags: selenium, cucumber, bdd

I have written a feature file & a seperate step definition file for the same .Here main work is i want to verify the elements of a 'Register' page.

But as i execute the feature file , The "Null pointer exception" error could be seen here ".

My feature file is

```
Feature: Verify the Register page

            @TC2
            Scenario: Verify the Register link provided on Home Page

               Given user is on  HomePage
               When user clicks on register link
               Then user should be able to view  <fields> such as

               |fields|
               |First Name|
               |Last Name|
               |Address|
               |City|
               |State|
               |Zip code|
               |Phone|
               |SSN|
               |Username|
               |Password|
               |Confirm|
```

My Test Runner class is:

```
            package runner;

            import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

            import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
            import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;

            @RunWith(Cucumber.class)
            @CucumberOptions(
            features="D:\\Para_Bank_Cucumber\\Cucumber_Framework\\src\\main\\java\\ParaBank\\Cucumber_Framework\\Para_bank_TC_01.feature"
            , glue= {"StepFiles"}
            , dryRun= false
            ,monochrome=true
            , strict=true
            ,tags= {"@TC2"}
            )


            public class Test_runner {

            }
```

My step definition file (Code) is like:

```
            package StepFiles;

            import java.util.List;
            import org.openqa.selenium.By;
            import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
            import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
            import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
            import org.openqa.selenium.support.FindBy;
            import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
            import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

            import DataProvider.ConfigFileReader;
            import cucumber.api.DataTable;
            import cucumber.api.java.en.Then;
            import cucumber.api.java.en.When;



            public class ParaBank_TC_02_Step {

                public  WebDriver driver;
                ConfigFileReader configFileReader;



                @FindBy(xpath="//a[contains(text(),'Register')]")
                private WebElement register_link;

                  @When ("^user clicks on register link$")
                    public void click_register() throws InterruptedException
                    {
                         WebDriverWait wait=new WebDriverWait(driver,30);
                         wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(register_link));
                         //wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(),'Register')]")));
                         register_link.click();
                    }


                    @FindBy(xpath="//table[@class='form2']/tbody/tr/td[2]/input[@id='customer.firstName']")
                    private WebElement first_name;

                    @FindBy(xpath="//table[@class='form2']/tbody/tr/td[2]/input[@id='customer.lastName']")
                    private WebElement last_name;

                    @FindBy(xpath="//table[@class='form2']/tbody/tr/td[2]/input[@id='customer.address.street']")
                    private WebElement Address;

                    @FindBy(xpath="//table[@class='form2']/tbody/tr/td[2]/input[@id='customer.address.city']")
                    private WebElement city;

                    @FindBy(xpath="//table[@class='form2']/tbody/tr/td[2]/input[@id='customer.address.state']")
                    private WebElement state;

                    @FindBy(xpath="//table[@class='form2']/tbody/tr/td[2]/input[@id='customer.address.zipCode']")
                    private WebElement zip;

                    @FindBy(xpath="//table[@class='form2']/tbody/tr/td[2]/input[@id='customer.phoneNumber']")
                    private WebElement phone;

                    @FindBy(xpath="//table[@class='form2']/tbody/tr/td[2]/input[@id='customer.ssn']")
                    private WebElement SSN;

                    @FindBy(xpath="//table[@class='form2']/tbody/tr/td[2]/input[@id='customer.username']")
                    private WebElement Username;

                    @FindBy(xpath="//table[@class='form2']/tbody/tr/td[2]/input[@id='customer.password']")
                    private WebElement password;

                    @FindBy(xpath="//table[@class='form2']/tbody/tr/td[2]/input[@id='repeatedPassword']")
                    private WebElement repeat_pass;

                    @Then ("^user should be able to view  <fields> such as$")
                    public void verify_fields(DataTable testData)
                    {
                        List<String> all_fields=testData.asList(String.class);  

                        for(String fields_links:all_fields)
                        {

                            WebDriverWait wait =new WebDriverWait(driver,30);
                            wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(first_name));
                            JavascriptExecutor js=(JavascriptExecutor)driver;
                            js.executeScript("arguments[0].setAttribute('style', 'color: blue; border: 2px solid Magenta;');", first_name);             

                            wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(last_name));
                            js.executeScript("arguments[0].setAttribute('style', 'color: blue; border: 2px solid Magenta;');", last_name);          


                            wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(Address));
                            js.executeScript("arguments[0].setAttribute('style', 'color: blue; border: 2px solid Magenta;');", Address);

                            wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(city));
                            js.executeScript("arguments[0].setAttribute('style', 'color: blue; border: 2px solid Magenta;');", city);

                            wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(state));
                            js.executeScript("arguments[0].setAttribute('style', 'color: blue; border: 2px solid Magenta;');", state);

                            wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(zip));
                            js.executeScript("arguments[0].setAttribute('style', 'color: blue; border: 2px solid Magenta;');", zip);

                            wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(phone));
                            js.executeScript("arguments[0].setAttribute('style', 'color: blue; border: 2px solid Magenta;');", phone);

                            wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(SSN));           
                            js.executeScript("arguments[0].setAttribute('style', 'color: blue; border: 2px solid Magenta;');", SSN);


                            wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(phone));
                            js.executeScript("arguments[0].setAttribute('style', 'color: blue; border: 2px solid Magenta;');", phone);


                            wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(Username));
                            js.executeScript("arguments[0].setAttribute('style', 'color: blue; border: 2px solid Magenta;');", Username);

                            wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(password));
                            js.executeScript("arguments[0].setAttribute('style', 'color: blue; border: 2px solid Magenta;');", password);


                            wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(repeat_pass));

                            js.executeScript("arguments[0].setAttribute('style', 'color: blue; border: 2px solid Magenta;');", repeat_pass);



                        }
                    }

            }
```

Expected Result :-

```
        1. it should click on Register link.
        2. It should highlight the elements described in javascript executor.
```

Actual Result :-

`NullPointerException error could be seen on a page.`

Please help me in finding the root cause of this error. Could not find the root cause of this error.
    I have tried putting wait i.e Web driver wait , but could not solve the error.
    I have also posted my Test runner class for further clarity.

Please help me out on this error.
Help required in knowing the existence of NullPointerException error.

Should i increase the wait time of webdriver so that it could trace the element first & then perform the required action.

or there exist an error in javaScriptExecutor .

Comment: There are a lot of issues with your code. Don't mix steps and Page Objects together. I don't see initialization of `PageFactory` which initializes WebElements annotated with `@FindBy`. I don't see initialization of the `WebDriver` in `ParaBank_TC_02_Step`

Comment: Driver has not been initialized as in other step definition file i have already intialized the driver , using the same feature keyword again i.e @Given ("^user is on  HomePage$")
    public void user_homePage()
    {
     configFileReader =new ConfigFileReader();
     System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","D:\\chromedriver.exe");
     driver=new ChromeDriver();
     driver.get("https://parabank.parasoft.com/parabank/index.htm");
     driver.manage().window().maximize();
    }

Comment: What about other issues I listed? Where did you initialize `PageFactory`? `PageFactory.initElements(driver, PAGE_OBJECT)`?

Comment: public void Para_bank_TC_02_Step(WebDriver driver)
 {
  PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
 }

Comment: If you separate Page Object from the Step class, it will work

Comment: @Fenio : Do i need to create a separate java class for initializing Page Factory?

Comment: You should do that for multiple reasons. Increase code reusability, readability. Right now it looks like a spaghetti, is badly formatted and hard to read. Besides, instead of using the same javascript in almost all steps, you could just do a proper method in Page Object and invoke it. I can't answer your question because I would have to rewrite your whole solution and that's not the point of this site. I can only point you to a specific direction

Comment: Try to separate the code and then, ask your question again if the problem occurs. Right now you created too many dependencies in one class. Move the elements annotated with `@FindBy` to Page Object class. Try to use them in steps. Then, create methods in the Page Object to set desired attributes and use them in steps. The steps should be really simple. Code complexity should be moved somewhere else - Page Object for example